# SQL PLUS, Not In

Tags: sqlplus

[image: This is my table]

```
SELECT EMPNO
FROM  EMP
WHERE EMPNO NOT IN (SELECT MGR FROM EMP);
```

I expected the answer of this query should be

7654, 7499, 7844, 7900, 7521, 7369, 7876, 7934

but Oracle gave me 'no rows selected'

I'm curious why this is happening.

Comment: Not sure why it is happening.  Is MGR column is same datatype as EMPNO? 
 perhaps try this.  `SELECT EMPNO FROM  EMP WHERE EMPNO NOT IN (SELECT MGR FROM EMP WHERE MGR>0);`

Comment: @AllenKing your query gave me the answer i expected but still i don't know why this is happening...

Answer (score 1):

Because `MGR` column is nullable,  apparently, the compare operation with an integer is failing.  Therefore, you will need to pull `MGR` records that do not include null values.

`SELECT EMPNO FROM EMP WHERE EMPNO NOT IN (SELECT MGR FROM EMP WHERE MGR>0);`

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Actually I got
SELECT EMPNO FROM EMP WHERE EMPNO NOT IN (SELECT NVL(MGR,0) FROM EMP);